# Jenkins shared library: Unable to import a package `No such property`

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a file which loads a library dynamically like this

```
def lib=library(identifier: 'pipeline-core@master', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
       remote: 'https://scm.intra/scm/jenins/pipeline-core.git',
       credentialsId: 'bitbucket.service.user'
])).ch.swisscard.pipeline.util.Utils

defaultCdPipeline {}
```

Whereas `defaultCdPipeline` is a jenkins pipeline definition which uses the `Utils` class like

```
import ch.mycompany.jenkins.pipeline.util.*
...
Utils.isRunning()
...
```

The file structure is this:

```
+- src
|  +- mycompany
|     +- jenkins
|        +- pipeline
|           +- util
|              +- Utils.groovy
|              +- Commons.groovy
+- vars
   +- defaultCdPipeline.groovy
```

That works so far. When I look at the dynamic import my understanding I would use `lib` so `lib.isRunning()` rather than `Utils.isRunning()` but this generates the following error

> ```
> No such property: lib for class: groovy.lang.Binding
> ```

Why? Going forward I would like to use both `Utils.groovy` and `Commons.groovy`. This I would "preselect the package" as this is shown in [the example](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically)  thus only using `.ch.swisscard.pipeline.util`

```
def lib=library(identifier: 'pipeline-core@master', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
       remote: 'https://scm.intra/scm/jenins/pipeline-core.git',
       credentialsId: 'bitbucket.service.user'
])).ch.swisscard.pipeline.util

defaultCdPipeline {}
```

This however also does not work as the call `lib.Uils.isRunning()`

```
...
   stages {
      stage('Deployment') {
         steps {
            script {
               lib.Uils.isRunning()`
...
```

throws the same exception as mentioned above

> ```
> No such property: lib for class: groovy.lang.Binding
> ```

Content if `Utils`

```
package ch.mycompany.jenkins.pipeline.util

class Utils implements Serializable {

    @NonCPS
    def static String isRunning() {
        return "isRunning()"
    }
}
```

Can somebody shed some light into this issue and tell me how I can properly load a package/multiple classes?

Answer (score 0):

you should have only declare the library load like this:

```
def lib = library(
    identifier: 'pipeline-core@master', retriever: modernSCM
    (
        [
            $class: 'GitSCMSource',
            remote: 'https://scm.intra/scm/jenins/pipeline-core.git',
            credentialsId: 'bitbucket.service.user'
        ]
    )
)
```

assuming this is the groovy class:

```
package ch.mycompany.jenkins.pipeline.util

class Utils implements Serializable
{
    @NonCPS
    def static String isRunning()
    {
        return "isRunning()";
    }

    def String isItReallyRunning()
    {
        return "isItReallyRunning()";
    }
}
```

then you call a static method like this:

```
lib.ch.mycompany.jenkins.pipeline.util.Utils.isRunning();
```

and an instance method like this:

```
// call the constructor (you can also call a constructor with parameters)
def utils = lib.ch.mycompany.jenkins.pipeline.util.Utils.new();

// call your instance method
utils.isItReallyRunning();
```